# elementary but confounding question about integer matrices (related to hecke operators)

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, quantum-groups

Let $\Gamma(N)$ denote the kernel of the reduction map $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$

Let $p$ be a prime that is $1$ mod $N$, and let $M$ be the set of matrices

$$\left[\begin{array}{ll}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right]$$
with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$, $ad-bc = p$, and congruent to the identity mod $N$.

$M$ has the property that $\Gamma(N)M\Gamma(N) = M$.

In Drinfeld's paper "Two Theorems on Modular Curves", he claims that assuming for every $m \in M$, there is an $h\in\Gamma(N)$ such that $m(\infty) = h(\infty)$, THEN for any $m\in M$ and $\gamma\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, there is some $h\in\Gamma(N)$ such that $m\gamma(\infty) = \gamma h(\infty)$, where here we view all matrices as acting on the compactified upper half plane via fractional linear transformations.

This is equivalent to saying that there is some $h$ such that the left column of $m\gamma$ agrees with the left column of $\gamma h$.

Does anyone see why this is true?

thanks,

- will

Comment: Observe $M$ is stable under $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acting by conjugation.

Comment: As written, the matrix version of this need not work. Example put into answer.

Comment: Why does knowledge about the image of $\beta(\infty)$ determine the left column of $\beta$? Won't, say, $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&p\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{p&0\cr0&1\cr}$ both map $\infty$ to itself

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, good point, I did not look at the original setting.

Comment: Expanded question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128609/quick-question-about-drinfelds-2-page-paper-two-theorems-on-modular-curves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $$  N = 3, p = 7.  $$

$$ m = \left[\begin{array}{ll}4 & 3 \\ 3 & 4\end{array}\right].$$
$$ \gamma = \left[\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right].$$
$$ m \gamma = \left[\begin{array}{ll}7 & 3 \\ 7 & 4\end{array}\right].$$
It follows that
$$ h = \left[\begin{array}{ll}7 & x \\ 0 & y\end{array}\right]$$
and it is not possible for $h$ to have determinant $1.$

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but unfortunately we require that $h\in\Gamma(N)$. In particular, $h$ must have determinant 1.

Comment: Also, the assumption that $p\equiv 1\mod N$ has to come in somewhere.

Comment: I don't see why $h$ must be as you say. Why couldn't $h$ have entries $[[3,4],[4,3]]$?

Comment: You said you wanted $m \gamma$ and $\gamma h$ to have the same left column.